# Ubuntu becomes unresponsive if idle for even few minutes

Tags: freeze

I am using 64 bit Ubuntu 16.04 on a desktop machine with processor Intel® Core™ i5-4440 CPU @ 3.10GHz × 4 , Graphics Intel® Haswell Desktop.

```
top - 08:13:11 up 9 min,  2 users,  load average: 2.53, 3.09, 1.85
Tasks: 246 total,   2 running, 244 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  1.0 us,  0.7 sy,  0.0 ni, 72.6 id, 25.7 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  3936468 total,   162944 free,  2286332 used,  1487192 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  4081660 total,  4076748 free,     4912 used.   848212 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                                            
 1124 root      20   0  312268  86988  62816 S   3.3  2.2   0:13.68 Xorg                                                                                                                                                               
 2479 cosmic    20   0 1199140  76948  29780 S   2.3  2.0   0:20.16 compiz                                                                                                                                                             
 5962 cosmic    20   0  782252  49980  27000 S   1.7  1.3   0:00.85 /usr/bin/x-term                                                                                                                                                    
 2502 cosmic    20   0 1113928 306644  23904 S   1.3  7.8   0:15.79 albert                                                                                                                                                             
   46 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.7  0.0   0:00.66 kswapd0                                                                                                                                                            
 5808 cosmic    20   0  960756 186712 102360 S   0.7  4.7   0:26.12 chrome                                                                                                                                                             
 5933 cosmic    20   0 1155916 406220 147564 S   0.7 10.3   0:15.84 chrome                                                                                                                                                             
 6486 cosmic    20   0 1320292 273028  83056 S   0.7  6.9   0:09.44 chrome                                                                                                                                                             
    7 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3  0.0   0:01.08 rcu_sched                                                                                                                                                          
 2246 cosmic    20   0  432228   8128   6372 S   0.3  0.2   0:00.41 ibus-daemon                                                                                                                                                        
 3909 cosmic    20   0 1362236 211096  89576 S   0.3  5.4   0:37.22 chrome                                                                                                                                                             
 4429 cosmic    20   0  511588 142476 106632 S   0.3  3.6   0:26.09 chrome                                                                                                                                                             
 5006 cosmic    20   0 1081952 277900 127088 S   0.3  7.1   0:14.64 chrome                                                                                                                                                             
 6268 www-data  20   0  360732   5756   2192 S   0.3  0.1   0:00.05 apache2                                                                                                                                                            
 6411 root      20   0    7464   2252   1868 D   0.3  0.1   0:01.13 updatedb.mlocat                                                                                                                                                    
 6634 cosmic    20   0   42044   3756   3048 R   0.3  0.1   0:00.04 top                                                                                                                                                                
    1 root      20   0  119752   5284   3372 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.88 systemd                                                                                                                                                            
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd                                                                                                                                                           
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.02 ksoftirqd/0                                                                                                                                                        
    4 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.10 kworker/0:0                                                                                                                                                        
    5 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H                                                                                                                                                       
    8 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcu_bh                                                                                                                                                             
    9 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/0                                                                                                                                                        
   10 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/0                                                                                                                                                         
   11 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/1                                                                                                                                                         
   12 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/1                                                                                                                                                        
   13 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.05 ksoftirqd/1                                                                                                                                                        
   15 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/1:0H                                                                                                                                                       
   16 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/2                                                                                                                                                         
   17 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/2                                                                                                                                                        
   18 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.01 ksoftirqd/2                                                                                                                                                        
   19 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.10 kworker/2:0                                                                                                                                                        
   20 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/2:0H                                                                                                                                                       
   21 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/3                                                                                                                                                         
   22 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/3                                                                                                                                                        
   23 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.03 ksoftirqd/3                                                                                                                                                        
   25 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/3:0H                                                                                                                                                       
   26 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdevtmpfs                                                                                                                                                          
   27 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 netns                                                                                                                                                              
   28 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 perf                                                                                                                                                               
   29 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khungtaskd                                                                                                                                                         
   30 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 writeback                                                                                                                                                          
   31 root      25   5       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksmd                                                                                                                                                               
   32 root      39  19       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.04 khugepaged                                                                                                                                                         
   33 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 crypto                                                                                                                                                             
   34 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kintegrityd                                                                                                                                                        
   35 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 bioset                                                                                                                                                             
   36 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kblockd                                                                                                                                                            
   37 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ata_sff                                                                                                                                                            
   38 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 md                                                                                                                                                                 
   39 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 devfreq_wq                                                                                                                                                         
   40 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.11 kworker/u8:1                                                                                                                                                       
   41 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.05 kworker/1:1                                                                                                                                                        
   47 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 vmstat                                                                                                                                                             
   48 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 fsnotify_mark                                                                                                                                                      
   49 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ecryptfs-kthrea                                                                                                                                                    
   65 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthrotld                                                                                                                                                           
   66 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 acpi_thermal_pm                                                                                                                                                    
   67 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 bioset                                                                                                                                                             
   68 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 bioset                                                                                                                                                             
   69 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 bioset
```

Microcode:

```
$ dpkg -l intel-microcode | grep ii
ii  intel-microcode 3.20151106.1 amd64        Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs


$ dmesg | grep microcode
[    0.000000] microcode: CPU0 microcode updated early to revision 0x1e, date = 2015-08-13
[    0.064600] microcode: CPU1 microcode updated early to revision 0x1e, date = 2015-08-13
[    0.068710] microcode: CPU2 microcode updated early to revision 0x1e, date = 2015-08-13
[    0.072771] microcode: CPU3 microcode updated early to revision 0x1e, date = 2015-08-13
[    0.662411] microcode: CPU0 sig=0x306c3, pf=0x2, revision=0x1e
[    0.662444] microcode: CPU1 sig=0x306c3, pf=0x2, revision=0x1e
[    0.662491] microcode: CPU2 sig=0x306c3, pf=0x2, revision=0x1e
[    0.662505] microcode: CPU3 sig=0x306c3, pf=0x2, revision=0x1e
[    0.662622] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.01 <tigran@aivazian.fsnet.co.uk>, Peter Oruba
```

**Disk test**
[image: Disk Test]
**Initial list of extensions in Chrome**

(Striked out ones have been removed after observing that Google Chrome is the reason behind the freezing):

1. Adblock for Youtube™
2. Advanced Font Settings
3. Google Dictionary (by Google)
4. Grammarly for Chrome
5. RSS Subscription Extension (by Google)
6. ScribeFire
7. <strike>Google Docs Offline</strike>
8. <strike>Google Keep - notes and lists</strike>
9. <strike>Google Keep Chrome Extension</strike>
10. <strike>Google Sheets</strike>
11. <strike>Google Slides</strike>
12. <strike>Google Translate</strike>
13. <strike>Save to Google Drive</strike>
14. <strike>Memo Notepad</strike>
15. <strike>Pinterest Save Button</strike>
16. <strike>Quick Javascript Switcher</strike>
17. <strike>Awesome Screenshot: Screen capture, Annotate</strike>
18. <strike>Allow Copy</strike>
19. <strike>Google Docs</strike>
20. <strike>Sticky Notes</strike>
21. <strike>Word Replacer II</strike>

The problem is very annoying. All the buttons are nearly unresponsive always. For example, to close a browser window and folder, it takes multiple clicks and more than 30 seconds.

If the system is idle for few minutes, all the windows freeze and show "The window is unresponsive" and I need to force quit.

I am using Ubuntu for nearly 7 years now and never faced such a situation.

Please help.

Comment: How much RAM? How much swap? Do you have `intel-microcode` installed? Have you used the `Disks` application, "SMART data & testing", to view hard disk records... possible hard disk problem? Does running `top` in the terminal app give any clue about a process consuming lots of CPU time?

Comment: Added more information. RAM 4 GB, SWAP 4GB

Comment: You didn't say about the `intel-microcode` and the SMART diags. Also, try logging into the Guest account and see if it's as slow there also.

Comment: I don't know how to check those :) I was Googling to find out ways :)

Comment: in `terminal` type `dpkg -l intel-microcode | grep ii`. For SMART, start `Disks` app, select disk in left pane, go to "hamburger" icon in top-right of window, and select `SMART data & tests`.

Comment: OK, I see that you DO have `intel-microcode`installed. Good.

Comment: After the SMART stuff, try two things... reboot the computer, and then log into the Guest account and DO NOT use Chrome, and see if the problem happens there. Then log out and log into your own account, and DO NOT use Chrome (use Firefox, etc.) and see if the problem happens again. Report back.

Comment: (Just a comment: Firefox is always problematic for me. It always froze in the last few years. )

Comment: Everything seems fine after following the steps. Does that mean Google Chrome is the culprit? Even Firefox is working perfectly.

Comment: Possibly. That's why I had you not use Chrome. Keep testing. We'll troubleshoot Chrome extensions a little later. Report back.

Comment: Everything going smoothly even if left idle for hours.

Comment: Retry Chrome with user-added extensions disabled and see if the problem comes back. If not, re-enable **one** extension at a time and retest. **Logout between tests**. Report back. I'll make an answer out of our dialog when we get a little closer to the final solution.

Comment: ps: what is "albert"?

Comment: 'albert' is a search application installed in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lengthy dialog via the comments, initial result is that Chrome and/or its extensions is causing the problem. The user is testing individual extensions further, to determine if it's any particular one (there were a lot of them) causing the problem.

It's also suggested that the user investigate installing more memory into the computer. Size/cost depends greatly on how the memory is currently configured (ie: number of slots used/available, size of currently installed memory sticks, etc.)